# How can I remove line numbers from my paper which uses the LIPIcs class file?

Tags: line-numbering

How can I remove line numbers from my paper which is using the [LIPIcs](https://www.dagstuhl.de/en/publishing/series/details/LIPIcs) stylesheet? (This is needed, e.g., when submitting to arXiv or when submitting the final version of a paper.)

Comment: (This is a bit of an easy question, but just adding it because it's inconvenient to find.)

Answer (score 3):

From the [manual](https://drops.dagstuhl.de/styles/lipics-v2018/lipics-v2018-authors/lipics-v2018-manual.pdf), you can simply add `\nolinenumbers` in the preamble.

Comment: Please show a full but minimal example.